# Past or present tense for a hypothetical situation

Tags: tense-agreement

> Please let me know if you **have** a spare copy or **did** another run

Is it correct to employ present because the  first event has more chance to happen than the second (past simple)

Comment: It's nothing to do with the first event having more chance of happening. The present is "correct" if what you're asking is whether the other person *currently* has a spare copy. There could obviously be contexts where what you're asking is whether they had a spare copy last month, say (which they might have since passed on to someone else, so they don't have it *now* anyway). Asking *Please let me know if you **do** another run*, means either *Tell me **if and when** you do another run* (at some future point), or *Tell me if it's your **normal practice** to do another run* (every time).

Comment: I dont know if he has a spare copy and I don't know if  he is going to make another run  so which tense should I use past simple for both?

Comment: But you chose to say you *don't know if he **has** a spare copy* (i.e. - whether he's got that spare *at the time of asking*, not whether he *had* a copy some time ago). It's the difference between ***Do you have** a wife? (right now)* and ***Did** you have a wife? (at some time in the past)*. To repeat myself, you use the verb tense that reflects what you want to know - neither question is inherently right or wrong in itself, it just depends what you want to ask about.

Comment: Your question has two conditions, one about a present state, the other about the past (you are asking whether the other person did another run). It is possible to ask such a question. The tenses do not suggest the probability of each condition being true. If you intend to ask about "doing another run" at present you should use "if you are doing another run", and if you ask about a future activity you should use "if you do another run".

Answer (score 1):

The tense choices here have nothing to do with likelihoods.

You are asking which of the two things "have a spare copy" and "did another run" was true. This is an **inclusive *or***, or that both can true at the same time too: you could simultaneously have a spare copy on hand, and already did another run of something earlier.

Back to the question.

> you have a spare copy

This is one of the things in your inclusive or. This is the present tense, or that if the person ***currently*** has a spare copy.

> (you) did another run

The other thing in your inclusive or question. This is the past tense, or that if the person did another run **before**hand.

Structure:

The "you have a spare copy" and "(you) did another run" are just potential predicates in an inclusive or question. Tense doesn't affect the chance of one predicate of the inclusive or being true or not.